# как выполнить Get запрос к яндекс api в ASP.NET?

Tags: json, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, yandex-maps-api

Надо реализовать поиск по организациям. У «яндекса» есть под это дело [API](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geosearch/examples/geosearch_examples-docpage/)

Очень хочется сделать все без использования JS.
я пробовал сделать это так:

```
        string adres = "https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?";
        string lang = "ru_RU";
        string apikiy = "тут мой ключ";
        string name = "ашан";
        var uri = new Uri(adres + "text=" + name + "&type=biz&lang=" + lang + "&apikey=" + apikiy);
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var json = await client.GetAsync(uri);



        dynamic x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

но `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` просит обьект в виде строки, просто приписав `.ToString()` не помогает, ругается на другие ошибки. но самое интересное, что этот же код работает в Universal App.

Может, я вообще как-то неправильно пытаюсь выполнить запрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(page))
using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
{

    string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();


    if (result != null &&
    result.Length >= 50)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(result.Substring(0, 50) + "...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Console.WriteLine(result.Substring(0, 50) + "..."); но ведь это не консольное приложение а asp.net mvc

Comment: @worldXAKER  string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync(); вот тебе строка дальше делай с ней что хочешь.

Comment: System.Net.WebException: Невозможно разрешить удаленное имя: 'search-maps.yandex.ru'

Comment: со второго раза отработало, но result вообще не видно, отладчик говорит что её нет, ну и обратиться к ней я не как не могу

Comment: @worldXAKER посмотрите что пришло в response.StatusCode

Comment: у меня получилось вот так                                                         var uri = new Uri(adres + "text=" + name + "&type=biz&lang=" + lang + "&apikey=" + apikiy);
            var client = new HttpClient();

            var json = await client.GetAsync(uri);


            string content = await json.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            dynamic x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
            int a = 0;
            string b = x.features.properties.CompanyMetaData.name;                            и согласно документации в переменной b должно быть имя компании, но там null

Comment: @worldXAKER features это массив обращайтесь через индекс. x.features[index].properties.CompanyMetaData.name

Comment: не помогло, все равно null

Comment: @worldXAKER а в string content не пустая?

Comment: нет, не пустая.

Comment: @worldXAKER это Json надо уметь с ним работать.Покажи что пришло.

Comment: вот что у меня есть, я хочу в переменную записать поле name https://pp.vk.me/c629427/v629427878/42236/_m_VUp8LV5I.jpg

Comment: @worldXAKER ... мне нужна строка что в string content, чтобы посмотреть структуру Json.

Comment: https://pp.vk.me/c629427/v629427878/4224e/1xV39hP-QII.jpg

Comment: Я думал посмотреть тестовый файл,а не скрин. Судя по нему вот x.SearchResponce.features[index].properties.CompanyMetaData.name. Если все же зальешь текстовый файл скажу точно. А вообще почитай про Json, если ты хочешь работать с API.

Comment: https://vk.com/doc38236878_437375754?hash=83e92ca058036f3389&dl=08fa361712111078e0 а что почитать про json можно?

Comment: @worldXAKER http://www.json.org/json-ru.html. Вам надо подучить основы программирования. Мой ответ x.features[index].properties.CompanyMetaData.name оказался изначально верным. index это номер элемента в массиве, если вы этого не знаете рано вам лезть в API.

Comment: до x.features[index].properties.CompanyMetaData.name я и сам додумался, но так не работает, а вот с  x.SearchResponce.features[index].properties.CompanyMetaData.name все ок